# Query for filling Sequence number on child rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

My structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Child (id, parent_id, seq_no);
```

I need an UPDATE statement to make the sequence number 1,2,3, etc. for every parent.

So for example:

```
1, 10, 1 
2, 10, 2
3, 10, 3
4, 20, 1
5, 20, 2
```

How can I do this with one SQL query? (Oracle 10)

Comment: It might be simpler to have a view that generates the `seq_no` on the fly, using `row_number()`, rather than maintaining the value in the table. You wouldn't have to worry about calculating new or changed values as data is added and removed. Depends on your needs, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an *update* question.  Oracle, unfortunately, does not support updatable CTEs (like SQL Server) nor does it support `update` with a `join` statement.  Here is one way of doing this in Oracle:

```
update child
    set seq_no = (select count(*)
                  from child c2
                  where c2.parent_id = child.parent_id and
                        c2.id <= child.id
                 );
```

Comment: I went with the row_number() solution (modified it to work with an update), which was quite slow btw, but I will agree that this is the more elegant option.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
insert into child
select id, parent_id, 
row_number() over (parition by parent_id order by id) seq_no
from parent
```